# How to find the minimax facility location if the facility can be on any edge

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

Given a weighed graph, how to find a location such that the maximum distance from this location to any point one the graph is minimized?
Notice: The facility location and the farthest point can be on both vertices and edges.
For example, the minimax facility location in the following graph is the star, and the triangle is the farthest point with a distance of 22.

**[example image]**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem if the facility location can only be on vertices (using Dijkstra ), but i have no idea since it can also be on edges.